# Communication between Service and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, service, communication, receiver

So, I've this `HugeService` which periodically gets `DataX`.
In `HugeService` I also register a `ImportantBroadcastReceiver` who is listening to important event Y.

Whenever `ImportantBroadcastReceiver` hears important event Y, I have to go and ask `HugeService` to tell me the current [periodical] `DataX`.

My idea:

Whenever `ImportantBroadcastReceiver` is called I should go and ask `HugeService` data via some kind of callback, but then again, how does this part work? Is it good idea to pass `HugeService` instance into `ImportantBroadcastReceiver`s constructor and then call static method that retrieves data (as Receiver strongly depends on Service [it's created from there])? Or is there other/better ways to handle this?

Comment: HugeService you mean Android Service? If yes, then you need to call startService() to call the service and pass the needed data using intent.

Comment: So, everytime I want Receiver to fetch data from Service I have to call startService (which would work like a callback)? This does not sound right to me at all and I certainly do not want to start service multiple times.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService. This is what you are looking for I guess. And startService() doesnt start you Android service multiple times. Multiple requests to start the service results in multiple corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand().